# How to get the next obj when looping in the django model

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

This is the code:

```
{% for o in page_obj.object_list %}
                <tr style="color:#4A3C8C;background-color:{% cycle '#E7E7FF' '#F7F7F7' %};"> 
                  <td align="center"> {{o.terminal_id}}</td>
                  <td align="center"> {{o.time_stamp}}</td> 
                  <td align="center" class="lat"> {{o.latitude|floatformat:"6"}}</td>
                  <td align="center" class="lng"> {{o.longitude|floatformat:"6"}}</td> 
                  <td align="center"> {{o.speed}}</td>
                  <td align="center"> 
                    <script>
                        $("script").last().parent().parent()
                    </script>
                  </td>
                  <td align="center"> {{o.speed}}</td>
                  <td align="center"> {{o.adress_reality}}</td> 
                </tr> 
            {%endfor%}
```

I want to get the next object after `'o'` object. 
How do I get the next from the `'o'` object? Alternatively, how to get the next object in the python file  that  i can  show this in the html as shown below?

`{{ o.next_obj }}`

thanks

Comment: What do you imagine that this "next_obj" will contain, and in what way will it be useful?

Comment: i want to  use this obj and the next obj to Calculate the distance between two points

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access multiple objects within a forloop, (although this is not a good design idea, but that is a separate discussion entirely.) you don't loop on the objects, but a counter and access the respective objects' counters moved around.

```
#In your view
obj_count = range(page_obj.object_list.count())

{% for i in obj_count %}

    o.i                   # Will access current object
    o.i+1                 # Will access the next object

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use get_next_by_FOO ?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO

If the field is not generated on the fly, you could add to your model (naively):

```
class MyObj(models.Model):
    lat = ...
    lon = ...
    def get_next_by_id(self):
        return self.objects.get(id=self.id+1)
```

And use `{{ o.get_next_by_id.lat }}`

Otherwise it is a good use for the [templatetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), see the tag section but require more code.
If you provide me a more detailed example of what you are doing i could try to give you a generic templatetag which might work in your case.

Good luck.