# how to get the next obj in this place

Tags: python, loops

this is my python code :

```
a=['aaa','bbb','oooo','qqqq','gggg']
for i in a:
    print i #how to get the next obj in this  place .
```

i want to get next code when i get the `i` element ,

thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Show what the output should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [the `zip` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to get both the current and next item in the list in the `for` loop.  So the `for` loop is iterating through the list and the list offset by 1 at the same time:

```
for this,after in zip(a,a[1:]):
    print this,after
```

However, `zip` stops at the end of the shortest list so you won't get to process the last element of your list.  If this is a problem use [`izip_longest` from `itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

```
import itertools
for this,after in itertools.izip_longest(a,a[1:]):
    print this,after
```

In this case `after` will be `None` for the last item in the list.

`izip_longest` was introduced in Python 2.6 so if you're running an earlier version you could achieve the same effect by hand by appending `None` on to the end of the shorter list:

```
for this,after in zip(a,a[1:] + [None]):
    print this,after
```

You can use `{% for x, y in somelist %}` in a Django template but you would need do the `zip` in your model and store that in a variable passed to the template.

Comment: 'module' object has no attribute 'izip_longest'

Comment: @zjm1126 - `izip_longest` was introduced in Python 2.6.  I guess you're running an earlier version.  I've edited the answer to show an alternate method that will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier just to enumerate the list for this:

```
a=['aaa','bbb','oooo','qqqq','gggg']

for idx, item in enumerate(a):
    print item
    if idx < len(a)-1:
       print a[idx+1]
```

(edit: fixed for `IndexError`)

Comment: This will implode once it hits the last element.

Comment: can this used to django template . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012973/how-to-get-the-next-obj-when-loop-the-django-model

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def twobytwo(it, last_single=False):
...     guard = object()
...     oe = guard
...     for e in it:
...         if oe != guard:
...             yield oe, e
...         oe = e
...     if oe != guard and last_single:
...         yield oe, None
... 
>>> for a, b in twobytwo(['aaa','bbb','oooo','qqqq','gggg']):
...     print a, b
... 
aaa bbb
bbb oooo
oooo qqqq
qqqq gggg
>>> for a, b in twobytwo(['aaa','bbb','oooo','qqqq','gggg'], last_single=True):
...     print a, b
... 
aaa bbb
bbb oooo
oooo qqqq
qqqq gggg
gggg None
>>>
```